# php, iconv() function error message

Tags: php, iconv

My text file contains the following string: "ãéðä".
My PHP batch to convert that string goes like this:

```
<?php
$text = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1", "ãéðä");
echo $text;
?>
```

When I run the code I get the converted text I want .
In a case i have more then one such string, I use the following code:

```
<?php
$myFile = 'test.txt';
$myHandle = fopen($myFile,'r');
$myText = fread($myHandle, filesize($myFile));
$ridComma = explode(',',$myText);
foreach($ridComma as $item)
{
$text = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1", $item);
}
fclose($myHandle);
?>
```

This time I get the following error:

```
Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 8
```

With the same conversion function I get the conversion in one batch and an error in the other !
Could anyone explain me why?
Thanks !

Comment: Are you certain that the file `test.txt` was saved with ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Comment: There is no errors in code. You have incorrect input in file. Use answer from Artjoman

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$text = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $item);
```

It will ignore illegal characters and remove them.

Comment: Thanks, this time the output eas: 'ÿþãéðä;

Comment: @Dai, I saved as "ansi" then "UTF-8", then "unicode", then "unicode big endian". I didn't get errors but the output remained gibrish.

Comment: There is one more option - to use function `mb_convert_encoding`
`$utf_8 = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8", "windows-1251");` In case you have `mb_string` extension installed

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the solution to my problem by. saving the text file via  notepad++ using: Encode in UTF-8 without BOM.